# From XPath result to simple array. How i can to do it without use foreach (or scan array)

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Using this query:

```
$xml->xpath( "/root/label//@name" );
```

I get this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Pippo
                )
        )
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Caio
                )
        )
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sempronio
        )

)
```

How i can have array with this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Pippo
    [1] => Caio
    [2] => Sempronio
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: _without use foreach (or scan array)_ I think there is a magic wand over there in the corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply cast every element to string through [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map):

```
$elements = $xml->xpath('/root/label//@name');

$names = array_map(fn(SimpleXMLElement $element) => (string) $element, $elements);
```

Or, with PHP < 7.4:

```
$elements = $xml->xpath('/root/label//@name');

$names = array_map(function (SimpleXMLElement $element) {
    return (string) $element;
}, $elements);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kEvLf)**

Note that `array_map` does loop over every element in the background.